# iOS Network Extension does not run after attaching to process

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, networkextension

I wrote a simple Network Extension for iOS:

```
class CFilterDataProvider: NEFilterDataProvider {

override func startFilter(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    NSLog("startFilter...")
    
    // Add code to initialize the filter.
    completionHandler(nil)
}

override func stopFilter(with reason: NEProviderStopReason, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Add code to clean up filter resources.
    NSLog("stopFilter")

    completionHandler()
}

override func handleNewFlow(_ flow: NEFilterFlow) -> NEFilterNewFlowVerdict {
    // Add code to determine if the flow should be dropped or not, downloading new rules if required.
    return .drop()
   }
}
```

After attaching to a process with Xcode, startFilter does not called in any situation.
My logs also indicate that function called successfuly but no action after attaching.

What's the reason for that?